# FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError (factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:73:in `lint')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I can't understand why this factory is invalid (**FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError (factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:73:in `lint'**).
Here it is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :building do
    sequence(:map_index)  { |n| "#{n}" }
    static_building_id 1
    finished_at Time.now + 1.hour #This row is the problem!
    user
  end
end
```

Here is the `user` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email)  { |n| "test_mail#{n}#@gmail.com" }
    sequence(:password)  { |n| "password-#{n}" }
    sequence(:username)  { |n| "username-#{n}" }
  end
end
```

And this is my `schema.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140726162156) do
  create_table "buildings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "static_building_id"
    t.integer  "level"
    t.datetime "time_creation"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "map_index"
    t.datetime "finished_at"
  end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Building  < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user

        validates :map_index, length: { in: 0..10}
        validates :static_building_id, length: { in: 0..10}
        validates :map_index, :static_building_id, presence: true

        before_create :initialize_building

        private

        def initialize_building
            self.level = 1
        end

    end
```

Note that **without** the column `finished_at` (both in the db and in the factory) everything works well... Any idea?

Comment: is the test db in sync with your schema?

Comment: @xlembouras I think so, I have `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` in my spec_helper, I also try to update it manually but anything change

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: The factory girl code seems to say that this error indicates that the model built by the factory is not valid (as in does not pass validations) but not sure why that would be in your case

Comment: Did you try using `Time.zone.now + 1.hour` ? Time.zone.now creates a different type of object which is valid for a datetime field, maybe that was creating the issue, I don't know.

Comment: @FrederickCheung was right: I comment the validations in my model and everything works well. Now I uncomment the validations and it is all ok! Unbelievable. by the way, the problems are in the validations, not in the date format